# Hugging Face T5 model that is not pre-trained and training it

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, training-data, huggingface

I want to use the Hugging Face T5 model to do summarization but I want to train the model with my own dataset.

How can I get the T5 model such that it has not been trained yet? And what steps do I need to take to train it?

Currently I am look at this tutorial:
https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/summarization

I also found this code which allows me to get a T5 model without weights but how can I train it with my own data?
[How to use architecture of T5 without pretrained model (Hugging face)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73700165/how-to-use-architecture-of-t5-without-pretrained-model-hugging-face)